# Illustrator to Word - Text Size Large (scaling issue)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, microsoft-word

On windows, when exporting text (and more broadly any image) developed in illustrator to word, by dragging it from illustrator to word, there appears to be an issue with text size - the text from illustrator is much larger in font size than what it should be according to word. Attached below is an image to show what is occurring. The text above was drag and dropped into word from illustrator. The text below was typed on word. Both were set at size 12 (the text on top, set to size 12 on illustrator and the text at the bottom set to size 12 on word),

[image]

Is there a way to get illustrator to export to the correct size on word? Interestingly, this issue does not seem to occur on mac!

Also, I require the crisp vector image output supported by drag and drop (rather than a lossy png file) as I need to export the word file to PDF.

Comment: Overall, the problem with this while process is the use of Word. I would ultimately suggest that if you have the entire Creative Suite at your disposal, which I'm assuming with the use of Illustrator, it would be better to use InDesign for the page layout. Vectors "drag" properly into InDesign and, although it does actually "work" to drag art from Illustrator into Word, my best guess is that Word is converting it to it's own image type when placed. This is probably the root cause for things not looking the same between programs.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the method you are using and found that vector art, as opposed to text, transferred similar to actual typed text:

[image]

The top line being text typed into Word and the bottom line being a vector shape (**text converted to outlines**). Other than the kerning and color, they appear similar.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop is a very easy shortcut to move things around but you also get the results based on the efforts you invested in that action. In general this means: poor results a lot of time and less control as well.

Illustrator is a high quality vector software while Word is a text processing software, they do totally different things.

MANY software do not support good conversion by drag and drop, especially when you use 2 different families of software (Adobe + Microsoft). And Mac has better drag and drop than Windows since forever.

> For optimal results, you should simply [save your vector as a file that
>   Microsoft Word accepts](https://superuser.com/questions/426405/importing-an-eps-vector-file-to-microsoft-word-without-losing-quality), then import that image into your Word file (not drag and drop).
>
> Try vectorizing (eg. do a create outline) your text first from
>   Illustrator; it's probably normal the size changes since they manage
>   the fonts differently.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What I've done. I created an *Illustrator* file with a single line of text, then I made a clipping mask around the text with a width equal to the width of A4 paper which I'll be using for my *Word* document, saved the file as `*.emf`. Then created a *Word* document, typed the same line with the same font size, inserted previously saved vector image, made sure that the image size is equal to the width of the page width, i.e. the exported image hasn't been scaled. After that I've saved the Word document as `*.pdf` file and opened it with *Illustrator*.

When now back again in *Illustrator* I've aligned two lines of text: one typed inside *Word* and one that has been typed inside *Illustrator* and then inserted in the *Word* document. As you can see there is a slight difference in letter distance (see how, when aligned, the text got bolder), but other than that the lines looks identical.